# COVID-19 cases broken down by whether the individuals are vaccinated, and if so, with which vaccine

Tags: data-request, medical, covid19

I'm looking for a dataset that contains number of COVID-19 cases broken down by whether the individuals are vaccinated, and if so, with which vaccine.

I'd prefer if the COVID-19 cases broken down by day and country, similarly to https://studylib.net/coronavirus:

[image]

(but the screenshot is missing vaccine info)

Answer (score 2):

The Swiss government just expanded their data to include infections of fully immunized people (include brand of vaccine)

https://twitter.com/BAG_OFSP_UFSP/status/1423245231856754689

[image]

The API notes are here:

https://www.covid19.admin.ch/api/data/documentation#v0160

From here https://www.covid19.admin.ch/en/overview you can also download the data as JSON/CSV

[image]

The URLs are changing, but you can use this curl script to download the current data: https://gist.github.com/rkaravia/36e461305bed8cf3fb62be4ea61c3325

Or see more on this page: https://opendata.swiss/en/dataset/covid-19-schweiz